# website occupying half the width on large monitors. is it bad?

Tags: website-design, size

I'm learning that my website looks like it has decent amount of content when viewed on small monitors but when viewed on large monitors, it looks like there is hardly any content at all.

If I encapsulte all my content inside a div tag and set it to a maximum fixed width (so my website is the same width on monitors exceeding a certain width for screen size), is this a bad thing or good thing for seo?

The reason I ask is because on my site with large screen width monitors, the ad is nearly touching a large image but on monitors with smaller widths, there is text between the bottom of the ad unit and the image and I know setting my whole site to a fixed width fixes this problem but I don't know if this is good or bad for seo.

Comment: `good or bad for seo.` It's indirectly bad because UX has a role on long term SEO.

Comment: net thing you'll know, the screen resolutions will be so huge that 99% of sites will look incomplete because text runs across the entire screen in one or maybe two lines.

Comment: Not really @Mike, that's why you should opt to use fluid and responsive website design. Screens will get bigger, designs need to adapt. I've already built websites for 1440p and 2160p... cratering for different and high resolutions is an easy task... and you shouldn't expect the same experience on all devices... you should however expect a good experience on all devices.

Comment: @Mike Truth. But to help that, you can scale the text using `vw`'s based on viewport ratio of some sort, so text does not look so nasty on giant screens. You should still media query to make sure it doesn't get tiny/giant in edge ranges though.

Comment: Bad for SEO might be at some point, but bad for your usrers indeed, but you could always try to use css media query to strech your main container on 1720px on 1920px res for example.

Comment: As a UX issue, **nobody runs websites full width** on a large monitor.  The whole point is so you can lay 2-3 windows side by side.   Retail site? 2 other windows are researching specs or reviews or comparing your competitors.  Event ticketing site?  Their calendar and instant-messenger are also open so they can coordinate dates.  They may be 2-screening an MMO game, which are infamous for making players sit around and wait.  You are not the center of your visitors' world, respect that.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, as far as SEO is concerned, it does not matter how small your website content looks on larger monitors. Website width does not directly affect SEO but website should be accessible and visible to the search engines.

But it's important for user experience and visitors.

So make sure you check your website on [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) tool and pass **User Experience** checklists.

Also don't go liquid on extra large monitors, use 50-60% of browser width for those monitors.

If you are not doing already, you can add couple of relevant images in each article to increase content length.

Also, review your website analytics, and try to find the screen size for majority of your visitors.

I found 92% of visitors on my website were using smaller screen than 900px, so I stopped investing tons of times on larger monitors and more time on optimizing user experience for mobile phones and tablets.

Comment: So you're saying I should use 900px as my target width and any screen over that means I should half the width?  I may need to revisit analytics again, but as for page speed insights right now, I basically got perfect (minus some points due to google adsense ads)

Comment: Please learn more about: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24406/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-fluid-and-responsive-design

Comment: @Mike no, I said do not fix the wrapper width in pixels but in percent for extra large monitors. For monitors have larger resolution than 1600px, use wrapper maximum width 50%-60%. On large monitors, you can also add additional top/bottom margins on ads.

Answer (score 1):

To give better user experience your website should look great on all resolution , at least in most of the commonly used monitors your website should look great.

For mobile, better have a minimalist website which is convenient  to browse and do business with your website.

When you don't have a pleasing/attractive website customer will exit quickly. Mostly visitor takes less than 2 ~ 3 seconds to decide to continue browsing your website or exit your website, this may be called "first impression".

Looks like, you are using fixed width. This is kind of old web design. Mostly nowadays everyone , even most of the templates available are with responsive design. Rather than using fixed with, you have to use the % of the width. This will help you to come up with responsive / fluid design.

Check this link: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24406/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-fluid-and-responsive-design

If your website design is not good or converting users to goals, then spending any amount of money on Advertisement may not give better results.

Comment: I have a separate mobile site for smaller resolutions but my concern is more for users with very high resolutions. Right now, my site is mostly fluid (with the exception of the fixed width/height adsense ad) but the fluid design makes the site look like there's hardly any content on high resolutions.

Comment: Very few people consider very large displays when thinking about responsive design. It's not easy... fixed width makes it look very small which is your problem. Totally fluid makes the text rows too long and weird looking. I used to make it fluid and take up maybe 70% of the screen no matter the size - but now days I'm trying to think about content first (and mobile first). What is important on the page? Is it first? It should be. Can you show something for large displays on the sides instead of after the article? Try to give large displays something extra if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines cannot determine **intent** based on display of content so, no, this does not affect SEO. Others are saying UX is an issue but search engines, again, cannot determine intent so, again, no, it does not affect SEO. To penalize you for this would be similar to penalizing a mystery site for a one word, centered index page.

However, if people hate your display and don't visit anymore for that reason, then, yes, it affects SEO.